# jQuery not being added correctly onto html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `example.js` file which uses jQuery. I have installed jQuery using `npm install jquery` and inserted it in the html file as following:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
</head>
```

`example.js` looks like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
$(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

I was expecting an alert message to show that jQuery has been added properly, however, nothing is happening. When I do the following:

```
<head>
//
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function() {
    alert(1);
});
</script>
//
</head>
```

It works. I am not sure why it does not work when I do the same thing but with the code inside the `.js` file. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `npm` is for installing node.js packages, it has nothing to do with client-side javascript.

Comment: You don't need to use `import` in `example.js`. jQuery is loaded as a global variable. Just get rid of the `import` line and it will all work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a browser, `import` only works when the importing script is `type=module` and when the imported script is written as a JavaScript module. Since your script isn’t such,  you will see an error message about `import` not being supported if you look at the Console in the developer tools in your browser.

**Learn to use the developer tools**, especially the Console and Network tabs, they are among the most valuable tools browsers provide to help you find why code doesn’t work the way you expect.

If you use `import`, then you use it **instead** of loading the script with a `<script>` element (and depending on a global variable instead of a specified import).

When you use it, the string you import from needs to be either a URL to the JS file *or* a keyword described by [an import map](https://web.dev/import-maps-in-all-modern-browsers/).

Installing a module using `npm` is primarily intended for use by Node.js and *not* by web browsers. It is possible to use some modules from npm with web browsers but you will need a way to take the *right* files from the *node_modules* directory where they are installed and give URLs that the browser can access them from. It is common to use a tool like Webpack or Parcel to convert modules (using Node.js resolution of files) into a bundle for loading in browsers.